# Laravel Eloquent insert 3 rows at once with timestamp

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm making a site with Laravel 5.2

I would like to do is

- `INSERT` 3 rows at the same time
- The new 3 rows have to contain timestamp `created_at` `updated_at`.

With the `Query Builder` method `insert`, Yes, it does insert 3 rows at once by passing an array like:

```
GroupRelation::insert([
    [
        'application_id'    => $applications[0]->a_id,
        'group_id'          => $group->id,
    ],
    [
        'application_id'    => $applications[1]->a_id,
        'group_id'          => $group->id,
    ],
    [
        'application_id'    => $applications[2]->a_id,
        'group_id'          => $group->id,
    ],
]);
```

The code above works fine. But this cannot touch the timestamp. Which means the `created_at` `updated_at` will be null.

However, if I changed the method `insert` to `create`:

```
GroupRelation::create([
   ... 
]);
```

It received the error:

```
ErrorException in Model.php line 2983:
preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

If I'm not wrong, it seems like `create` can just accept 1 row at the same time, right?

I know `insert` is not a part of `Eloquent`. `Eloquent` fires timestamps but `Query Builder` does not.

So my questions are:

1. `insert` method can accept 3 rows at one time, but how can I fire the timestamp manually?
2. By `1.` I've tried to add `'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),` at each items of the array. But the controller is unclear and horrible.
3. How can I pass an array of 3 items to `create` method in order to fire timestamps?
4. Is it a good idea to call `create` inside the loops?

PS. `protected $guarded = []` was assigned to empty array so would not receive Mass Assignment Exception.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`insert()` is a part of Query Builder, so it doesn't use Eloquent features.

You can't pass 3 items to `create()` method, only one. And using `create()` inside loops is terrible idea.

You should add these fields manually when doing bulk insertion:

```
[
    'application_id'    => $applications[0]->a_id,
    'group_id'          => $group->id,
    'created_at'        => Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at'        => Carbon::now(),
],
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've done that! But I have 3 rows. As you see, I have 3 items of the array. Each of them is almost same and a little difference of  `$applications` index among them.    If I manually add `created_at` `updated_at` to the array set, the code is triplicate. Any further ideas?

Comment: I am sure there is already question like that, why instead of searching for duplicate you choose to answer? I am just curious...

Comment: @Benyi you can create an array and then just iterate over it and add timestamps to each item. It's the best solution you've got.

Comment: @Kyslik usually people who post links to 'duplicates', post links to not really related questions. I hate that and prefer to answer questions with related code and explanation. If you found helpful similar question, please post the link.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyMezenin and @Kyslik! This is a good idea for me. Hope AlexeyMezenin's answer and suggestion are helpful to that people who are confusing with timestamp not fired, and `create` no bulk insertion. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin By your suggestion provided yesterday, I've used `array_walk()` walking through each of the item, and create new sub-items (`created_at`, `group_id`...) of that item in the closure. Finally I got the finished array with no triplicate same code. That is what I want. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `dateTime` class :

```
[
    'application_id'    => $applications[0]->a_id,
    'group_id'          => $group->id,
    'created_at'        => new \dateTime,
    'updated_at'        => new \dateTime,
],
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In this question, the way to get current time is not relevant. It's about timestamp not updating by `insert()` method. And it can't  insert more than 1 row by `create` method which is able to update timestamp.